# Forecasting of Images using ConvLSTM2D

Tags: keras, sequence-to-sequence

I am working on a problem of seq2seq modelling using ConvLSTM2D layer in keras. Implementation of convLSTM in keras allows user to control over output sequence using 'return_sequence' option. When True, the size of output sequence would be same as input sequence and when False, the output sequence would be a single frame. My question is how can I control on size of output sequence when it is neither same as input sequence nor a single frame (next frame)? For example, forecasting next 6 images from past 20 images using convLSTM2D. Any help in this regard would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to predict the next one, and now, based on 21 images you predict the second one, and so on and so forth.